# How to use model class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use model class in my iOS app.I heard about that its increasing performance and development faster.
        I try to using it but not succeded. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you need help understanding how to create / use a model and why you should. I would suggest you first need to go read some books, take some online course etc about programming before asking questions on stackoverflow. This type of question is not suited for stackoverflow

Comment: Check this out https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/DefineYourDataModel.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can prepared model class like,

```
class ModelClass : NSObject
{
    var name : NSString!
    var age : NSString!
}
```

You can used model class wherever u need like this,

```
var objModel : ModelClass = ModelClass()

// set your values into models property like this

objModel.name = “Test” 
objModel.age = “12”
```